# How can I implement text to speech into this?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I am using OpenAI to talk to an AI but in order to speak to it I have to type in the prompt section where it says human, print the response, then it will speak to me but only once. Is there a way to implement text to speech into this and speech to text?

```
import os
import openai

openai.api_key = 'not saying my api key'

start_sequence = "\nAI:"
restart_sequence = "\nHuman: "

response = openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-002",
  prompt="The following is a conversation with an AI assistant. The assistant is helpful, creative, clever, and very friendly.\n\nHuman: Hello, who are you?\nAI: I am an AI created by OpenAI. How can I help you today?\nHuman: ",
  temperature=0.9,
  max_tokens=150,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0.6,
  stop=[" Human:", " AI:"]
)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using notebooks:

```
import os
from gtts import gTTS
from IPython.display import Audio, display

def talk(text):
    # convert text to speech, save to audio file 
    gTTS(text).save('temp.wav')
    # load audio file, play sound
    display(Audio('temp.wav', autoplay=True))
    # remove temporary file
    os.remove('temp.wav')
```